# How to create an accordion from this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problems trying to create an accordion on this code structure. I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```js
var allPanels = $('.abc').hide();

$('.click_acc').click(function() {
  //alert("thanks");
  allPanels.slideUp();
  $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  this is a faq question 1
  <span class="readLinkTag">
    <a class="click_acc" href="#">
      READ MORE 
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="abc">
    this is answer of faq question 1
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  this is a faq question 2
  <span class="readLinkTag">
    <a class="click_acc" href="#">
      READ MORE 
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="abc">
    this is answer of faq question 2
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Would you mind to replace your php code by created HTML code?

Comment: invalid HTML .... div as a sibling of li ???

Comment: To add to @reporter: The CSS and container HTML code would be of interest as well

Comment: You need to move the `div` into the `li`: the parent of `.click_acc` is a `span` that has no `next()` at the moment.

Comment: You might need to include your *other* accordion items.  As it stands, it looks like you have tabs rather than accordions - ie the `li`s and `div`s are in separate places of the code.  Normally, the `div` would be *inside* the `li` to provide valid HTML

Comment: In such a primitive form, that’s an accessibility nightmare. At least go with a Bootstrap collapse as a basis or something …

Comment: <li>
  this is a question
  <span class="readLinkTag">
    <a class="click_acc" href="#">
      READ MORE 
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
    </a>
  </span><div class="abc">
  this question answer
</div>
</li>

Comment: Please *edit* the question so that code can be formatted, don't add as a comment

Comment: Why is exactly this code structure relevant to you? I mean I would like to help you but I wouldn't go for such a hideous approach, also you are not giving enough info, you need vanilla JS/jQuery you need accordion with only 1 possible active / multiple at the same time, when you click on acc item it should close any other active or?

Comment: Ok guys sorry for mistakes. i have updated the code. I hope its make sense now.

Comment: Do you require the same structure, cause there certainly are better ones, do you need it to show only 1 tab at a time meaning if you click on innactive one it should close the current active, or do you need it to be able to show contents of more than 1 at a time?

Comment: Ok, I've converted your code to a snippet - and, with your updated html structure, it appears to work exactly as I'd expect it to work.  Can you describe the **actual problem you are having**.

Comment: From close vote: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour **and a specific problem or error**.*  "but it's not working" is not specific enough when it can be demonstrated to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to show hide and change arrow:

```
$('#click_acc').click(function() {
$('#abc').toggle('1000');
$("i", this).toggleClass("icon-circle-arrow-up icon-circle-arrow-down");});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it will toggle all faqs. I am using the same classes. As you can see here: http://luxofdubai.com/development/qutekwp/health-faq/

Comment: this code will help you in create accordian :------------------------------------------------------------------------------$('.menu').click(function () {
        $('.nav-item.show').not(this).removeClass('show');
        $(this).parents("li").addClass('show');
        $('.menu.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    })

Answer (score 0):

use slideToggle instead of slideUp and SlideDown

```js
var allPanels = $('.abc').hide();

$('.click_acc').click(function() {
  //alert("thanks");

  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  this is a faq question 1
  <span class="readLinkTag">
    <a class="click_acc" href="#">
      READ MORE 
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="abc">
    this is answer of faq question 1
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  this is a faq question 2
  <span class="readLinkTag">
    <a class="click_acc" href="#">
      READ MORE 
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
  <div class="abc">
    this is answer of faq question 2
  </div>
</li>
```